# How to POST a value to next page using JavaScript of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code looks like this.

```html
<a href="#" class="5" id="link">Next</a>
```

```js
<scipt>
    $('#link').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('class');
        $.post('nextpage.php', { class:val }, function(){
            window.location.href = "nextpage.php";
            return false;
        });
    });
</scipt>
```

This is my attempt. I've tried the above jQuery code with and without the function() inside $.post(). With function it just redirects the page with out posting the variable. Without that function it is not doing anything.

I have several links in my code with respective classes. I am not using its class for any styling. I just want to send the values of the class attribute of `anchor` tag with `id=link` to next page. And I want to do it by POST method and not by GET method. I want to do it by jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: You could use local storage to save the value. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html This is not something you would use Ajax for.

Comment: If you want it to act like you're submitting the form, why don't you just submit the form? The usual reason to use AJAX is so that you DON'T reload the page.

Comment: you are not sending anything to next page.. send json object not plain text.. check my answer

Comment: typo in <scipt> tag...

Comment: Answer by @user2853290 is correct and if you ever use to post value using ajax then send JSON object .. not text. check my answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this without form, you just do like this:

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="nextpage.php" method="POST">
    <a href="#" class="5" id="link">Next</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="class" id="class"/>
</form>
<scipt>
    $('#link').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('class');
        $("#class").val(val);
        document.getElementById("formName").submit();
    });
</scipt>
```

Comment: If you don't want to do like I suggest above. You could use session or something that saves the class value on server and then you could use it in the next time you request that page.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that post() is an AJAX thing and as such it does post but stays on same side. After that your window.location is a new request and variable is not sent that time.

In this case I would use submit() and have a form in HTML with hidden input that would "carry" the variable(s): http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

send json object in $.post()

```
var val = '{ "class" : "' +$(this).attr('class')+ '"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(val);
$.post('nextpage.php', obj, function(){
```

**EDIT**

what you want cannot be achieved because ajax cannot redirect.. and if you redirect using window location then it will not have POST data sent by ajax..

Comment: Yes it is happening.. ajax response from nextpage.php is coming. Try echoing class id sent to it.. and alert it in function..

Answer (score 0):

. First , u need to prevent direct redirecting because of  default click  event on a *anchor* tag

```
<scipt>
    $('a #link').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = $(this).attr('class');
        $.post('nextpage.php', { class:val }, function(){
            window.location.href = "nextpage.php";
            return false;
        });
    });
</scipt>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, First I hope this was not straight copy-pasted from your code. If so, you have a couple of typo's

```
<scipt> <-- Typo
    $('#link').click(function(){
        var val = $(this).attr('class');
        $.post('nextpage.php', { class:val }, function(){
            window.location.href = "nextpage.php";
            return false;
        });
    });
</scipt> <-- Typo
```

Next, this is an AJAX request, meaning that all of this will seemingly happen silently, unless you have some sort of callback (feedback from the server).

Try something like (taken directly from [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)):

```
  // Send the data using post
  var posting = $.post( 'nextpage.php' , { class: val } );

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
  });

<a href="#" class="5" id="link">Next</a>
<div id="result"></div>
```